# How to write a function defined by segments in a formula?

Tags: logic, arithmetic

I would like to define a function like $f(x) = 5$ if x is even, and $f(x) = 8$ if x is odd by using a first order logic formula. Is it possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Is not that clear what you mean "_by defining a function....by using a first-order logic formula".

I suppose that you meant if there is a formula in the the first-order language *of arithmetic* (also known as Peano Arithmetic or PA for short).

If that is the case then you can simply rephrase you can define your function through the following functional formula

$$\varphi_f(x,y) \equiv((\exists z. 2z=x)  \rightarrow y=5) \land ((\forall z. 2z \ne x) \rightarrow y=8)$$

Using the axioms of PA it is possible to prove that indeed
$$\forall x \exists ! y \ \varphi_f(x,y)$$
that is $\varphi_f$ is really a functional formula. Then you can say that $f(x)=y$ is a short-hand for $\varphi_f(x,y)$.

Alternatively if you are using also $\mu$-recursion in your arithmetic language you can define $f$ as 
$$f(x)=\mu_y \varphi_f(x,y)$$
(if you are not familiar with the formalism that means $f(x)$ is the minimal $y$ such that $\varphi_f(x,y)$ holds).

I hope this address your question.

Comment: Your guess is right. Thanks for the answer. I understand your answer. But I think that μ-recursion (or restricted μ-operator) is not part of the original first-order logic. I see it in Gödel's article in 1931 in form of εx[], but not in an ordinary book explaining first-order logic. My concern is in fact whether a function in first-order logic formula remains computable even when containing proposition in its definition. If proposition can be added to the definition of a function only by μ-recursion, then a function in formula is always computable.

Comment: @user49413 "My concern is in fact whether a function in first-order logic formula remains computable even when containing proposition in its definition." I'm not sure what that means, but it's certainly worth observing that not all first-order definable functions are computable. E.g. the characteristic function of the halting problem is first-order definable (in, again, $(\mathbb{N};+,\times$)). There is however a connection between computability-theoretic and syntactic complexity; specifically, the [quantifier structure of the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

Comment: Since O.P. is asking specifically about computability and especially godel's techniques, it might be worth modifying the formula to be $\dots (\exists z < x) \dots (\forall z < x) \dots$ , this is called "bounded quantifiers" and is what keeps the formulas directly computable.

Comment: @user49413 Then I guess that the only possibile definition is the one via abbreviation (i.e. you define the formula $f(x)=y$ as an abbreviation of the above mentioned formula.
About your concerns on $\mu$-recursion: actually you cannot replace any formula in the $\mu$-recursive definition of the function but only computable ones. In this case the definition works because the formula is of the form $\Sigma^0_1$, hence it is computable.

Comment: Minor point: the bracketing in your formula for $\phi_f(x,y)$ isn't right.

Comment: @RobArthan can you be a little more specific?

Comment: The structure of the formula should be $((\exists \ldots) \to y = 5) \land ((\forall \ldots) \to y = 8)$ ( a conjunction of implications that have quantified formulas on the left-hand sides) not $(\exists( \ldots \to y = 5)) \land (\forall (\ldots \to y = 8))$ (a conjunction of quantified implications).

Comment: @RobArthan....aaaaaaaaah right. Thanks for pointing out. Edited.